# Is `java` a reserved keyword in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reserved-words

I noticed that several JavaScript IDEs (e.g. Sublime) show the word `java` with a syntax highlighting like it is a reserved keyword.

Also older versions of Firefox have problems with a function called java.

```
function java() {
    alert("This function can not be called");
}
```

Is this actually a keyword? If yes what is it for?

Comment: Which version of firefox? I'd like to confirm that. No, it isn't a keyword or reserved word.

Comment: @cookiemonster: i cannot find the problematic version anymore right now. but i will keep looking and come back to you once i found it.

Comment: I went ahead and  downloaded Firefox 1, and made a test: `function java() { alert("Java Works"); } java();`, and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately the answer is **it is not a reserved keyword**, you should be safe in using `java` as a variable name.

But as noted on http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm it states that `java` is one of the words that *should have been reserved words*. And I believe the reasoning he is referring too is for [Java Applet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) integration.

It is hard to find references of this on the web because the technology is largely deprecated.  It appears that up until **Firefox 16** Mozilla included **Globals for `Packages`, `java`, and `netscape`** (See [**2.1.5 Deprecated Functionality: the Global Packages, java and netscape Keywords**](https://jdk6.java.net/plugin2/liveconnect/#JS_JAVA_CONVERSIONS))

The only bits of this I could find are referenced in Mozilla's [LiveConnect Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/LiveConnect) where you can see in [Java in Firefox Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Java_in_Firefox_Extensions) First the note

> **Note:** *The global java object has been removed in Gecko 16.0, so this page is out of date*

And then the sample code block:

```
var aJavaList = new java.util.LinkedList();
```

So basically before Mozilla had deprecated the global `java` object (and possibly applets were on the page?), this could have been a problem.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it's not actually Java keywords, as Javascript doesn't have anything to do with Java except borrowing the name.

The names were reserved in case they would be needed in future expansions of the language. From the [**ECMAScript Language Specification**](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-7.5.3):

`The following words are used as keywords in proposed extensions and are therefore reserved to allow for the possibility of future adoption of those extensions...`

**http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm**

Comment: The second link indicates that "java" *should have been* a reserved word (and I agree), but technically, it is not a reserved word.

Answer (score 2):

According to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

**No, it is not a reserved word.**

Taking and running your function in a browser console confirms this.